# How to properly set settings for RelativeLayout programatically?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, parameters

I'm creating a `RelativeLayout` programatically and I want to place three objects into it: a `ListView` and two `Button`s. I need to set some settings to properly locate them in the window. For now I'm doing it this way:

```
RekativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
rl.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

ListView listView = new ListView(context);
ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(jParser.getArrayList(), context);
listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(wWidth, wHeight));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams listParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wWidth, wHeight);
listParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
listParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
listView.setId(98515);
listView.setLayoutParams(listParams);

Button moreButton = new Button(context);
moreButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
moreButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
moreButton.setText("More");

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, listView.getId());
mButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, listView.getId());
mButtonParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
moreButton.setLayoutParams(mButtonParams);

closeButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
closeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
closeButton.setText("Close");

Button closeButton = new Button(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
cButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, listView.getId());
cButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, listView.getId());
cButtonParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
closeButton.setLayoutParams(cButtonParams);

rl.addView(listView);
rl.addView(moreButton);
rl.addView(closeButton);
```

but I guess this method requires much system resources and isn't acceptable. How should I set the settings properly?

Comment: `but I guess this method requires much system resources and isn't acceptable. How should I set the settings properly?` Could you argument that?

Comment: This is why layout resources exist.

Comment: @nKn my argument for this would be that creating new `RelativeLayout` object for EVERY view may consume much memory from the systme. But depending on your answer I now think that I am wrong! So this is the right way to programatically manage the layout?

Comment: My answer would be that it mostly depends on your layout, actually. You have 2 ways of defining a `View`, as a layout resource and dynamically (which is what you're doing). If you mean doing it this way, this is the correct way. 'More lines' doesn't mean more complex/inefficient, I think it will depend more on what you're placing into that `RelativeLayout` (heavy `ImageView`s, etc). After all, you're setting the same attributes as if you were defining a layout file, just in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine, given the question you asked. For the sake of the question I will still answer both. 
I think you meant [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). Which let's you set any attributes and customize how the View should behave. 
For instance, to create and set the basic height/width:

```
RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        myRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

===========================================================
Now, as far as you other doubts, your real question is if this is optimal and if there are any other ways. (While you should really create another question, I will still answer).
As mentioned in the commments, this is the main reason of xml resources. Here you create your layouts or views and just populate them with data.

Here's a quick guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

A quick breakdown: 
-res/layout/ is the directory where your layout xmls will be. ([LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html))
-Inside those you decalre other views (TextView, ImageView, etc).
-You must reference and inflate the resources to be able to call them in code.
-Once inflated you can call findViewById(resourceId) and cast View to the proper Widget (view) type.

Inflating and referencing view items requires a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Here's a quick guide to understand how it works: 
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Other references:
You might want to take a deeper look into [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: I am referring to these from a service so I cannot use findViewById and XML files. That's why I'm using RelativaLayout.LayoutParams programatically and create the layout at runtime. But thanks for the clarification anyway.

Comment: Then clarify what you are truly trying to do. A service as you said cannot and should not deal with any UI components. If anything it should notify an Activity back so it should update or handle UI changes. Or perhaps, you may want to start a new Activity altogether.